# CSS Positioning div on top with z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a container which has three divs. Each div contains a hidden div which has a 'hide' class (`display:none;`) inside which is supposed to show when hovering on its parent div.

I use `toggleClass('show')` to which makes the secretDiv display has a block. I need the secretDiv to be shown when hovering on the parent div.

The parent div should show on top of the div below, and not push the other divs

http://jsfiddle.net/2xLMQ/4/

--- HTML ---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="element">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" title="" />
        <div class="secretDiv hide">
            <p>Some secret text and stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="my image" title="image title" />
        <div class="secretDiv hide">
            <p>Some secret text and stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="element">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" title="" />
        <div class="secretDiv hide">
            <p>Some secret text and stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="my image" title="image title" />
        <div class="secretDiv hide">
            <p>Some secret text and stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

--- CSS ---

```
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
.row {height:160px;background:#dedede;float:left;width:480px;position:relative:z-index:1;}
.row .element {position:relative;z-index:9;text-align:center; float:left; background:#666;width:200px;padding:12px;margin:6px;}
.row .image {}
.row .secretDiv {background:#ff0000;padding:8px;}
```

--- JS ---

```
$('.element').hover(function(){
    $('.element .secretDiv').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2xLMQ/5/? Not sure what exactly you're after.

Comment: So what's the question

Comment: Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2xLMQ/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all change your selector to only match the respective hidden div:

```
 $('.secretDiv',this).toggleClass('show');
```

Then add another class on that item to display ontop of the others :

```
$(this).toggleClass('ontop');
```

And the class:

```
.row .ontop {z-index:10;background:orange;}
```

Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLMQ/8/)

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted, but why the extra .ontop class?

Comment: @j08691 just to allow more changes in div if he want to highlight like the background. But of course he can change just the `z-index` value

Comment: @Danko - sweet, your solution worked well. Exactly what I needed. Didn't know I could specify a class after (this) selector. Learned from your solution, thanks a lot. Chosen answer + upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add absolute positioning to your 'secret' div:

```
.row .secretDiv {background:#ff0000;padding:8px; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/2xLMQ/12/

As a bonus, I've edited your jQuery to show only the 'secret' div associated with each element:

```
$('.secretDiv', this).toggleClass('show');
```